# How to Present a floating point number using php

Tags: php, printf

I have a price database that stores numbers as floating point.  These are presented on a website.  Prices can be in the format.

```
x.x    (e.g. 1.4)  
x.xx   (e.g. 1.99)  
x.xxx  (e.g. 1.299) <-- new price format
```

I used to use the string format or `%.2f` to standardize the prices to two decimal places but now I need to show 3 as well but only if the price is 3 decimal place long.

```
e.g.   1.4  would display  1.40
       1.45 would display  1.45
       1.445 would display 1.445
```

The above formats would be the desired output for the given input.

using `%.3f` shows all with 3 digits.

```
e.g.   1.4  would display  1.400     
       1.45 would display  1.450    
       1.445 would display 1.445
```

But that is not what i want does anyone know the best way to do the following.

i.e.  any number should display 2 decimal places if it has 0 1 or 2 decimal places
      if it has 3 or more decimal places it should display 3 decimal places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would just format it to three places, then trim a final 0.

```
$formatted = number_format($value, 3, ".", "");
if (substr($formatted, -1) === "0") $formatted = substr($formatted, 0, -1);
```

Comment: what is the code for format_to_3 I tried sprintf($data,"%.3f") but i'm still getting 5.5 instead of 5.50 for numbers with only 1 decimal place

Comment: I would probably use number_format($data, 3, ".", "");

Comment: This partially answered so I will mark it it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Use this dude

```
number_format($data->price, 0, ',', '.');
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

Comment: This does the same as sprintf it just does either 2 decimals or 3.  I think from the documentation the '0' in your answer would give no decimal places wouldn't it..

Comment: I used number format in the final solution but I can only add one as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I did due to the need to cope with some special cases I had in the app.

1. count the number of dec places ($prices is a float from the database).
2. format based on the count in the places using a switch statement.
3. For all cases with less than 3 decimal places format with 2 (except zero)
4. For all other case format with 3.

   ```
   $decimals = strlen(substr(strrchr($price,"."),1));  
   switch ($decimals) {
       case 0: {
          if ($price != 0) {
              $price = number_format($price),2);
          }
          break;
       }
       case 1: {

          $price = number_format($price),2);
          break;
       }
       case 2: {

          $price = number_format($price),2);
          break;
       }
       default: {
          $price = number_format($price),3);    // three dec places all other prices
          break;
       }
   ```

   }

Thanks for the help...